# Jquery plugin not able to add a div

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-widgets

I am very new to jquery plugin and widgets, was just trying out a simple plugin, in which for the div I am trying to append a new div, but it's not able to attach and there are no errors, I am not able to figure out what is the mistake I have done.. The widget code goes below,`(function ($) {

```
jQuery.widget("ui.test", {
    options: {},
    _create: function () {
            this.element.append("<div>da</div>")
    },
    _destroy: function () { },
    _setOption: function (key, value) { }
});
```

}(jQuery));`

In the html I have a div with id="test" and it'been called like this,

```
$("test").test();
```

Comment: any error in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, in order to use [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) you need `# + id`, ex `#test` will select the element with id `test`

```
$("#test").test();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xnZtz/)

Comment: OMG!.. I don't know how i missed it.. may be that's why i shouldn't work for long hours :).. Thanks Arun